# Click on checkboxes that are dynamically growing with in the page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a query regarding the handling on check boxes in a section. The HTML code is.

```
<li id="SelfPay">
<a class="sections active" href="javascript:void(0);">Self-Pay</a>
<ul class="insurersDetail" style="">
<li class="SelectAllPayers" states="*">
<input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" name="selectAllCheckBox" onclick="stopPayerClick()"/>
<label for="selectAll" onclick="stopPayerClick()"> Select All</label>
</li>
<li class="" states="IA,WI">
<input id="AUX01" type="checkbox" name="PayerCheckBox" onclick="stopPayerClick()"/>
<label for="AUX01" onclick="stopPayerClick()"> AUXIANT</label>
</li>
<li class="" states="NE">
<input id="52312" type="checkbox" name="PayerCheckBox" onclick="stopPayerClick()"/>
<label class="" for="52312" onclick="stopPayerClick()"> Arbor Health Plan</label>
</li>
<li class="" states="IN">
<input id="00715" type="checkbox" name="PayerCheckBox" onclick="stopPayerClick()"/>
<label class="" for="00715" onclick="stopPayerClick()"> BCBS Indiana</label>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Currently there are 4 check boxes in the above code but there are some other check boxes in other parts of page which will be checked if I use the code below

```
IList<IWebElement> selectElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("checkbox"));
```

Please help me how to check only those 4 check boxes ignoring the rest of the checkboxes in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a proper selector that only targets those four elements.

```
By css = By.CssSelector("li#SelfPay input[type='checkbox']");
IList selectElements = driver.FindElements(css);
```

And, that should only return the four checkboxes under the `li` element with `id='SelfPay'`

Comment: This has helped me to get the desired result.Thanks for the help..!!